# How to solve this 'cannot find symbol' in java

Tags: java

I am a year 1 student and is extremely new to java programming, I really hope you guys could bear with my problems.  I have the following codes and it runs perfectly on Eclipse but could not run in terminal in Linux. The codes are below:

Person.java

```
package src2;

public class Person implements Runnable {

protected Bathroom bathroom;
private boolean isMale;

// Minimum time to idle
private int minIdleTime = 1000;

// Maximum time to idle
private int maxIdleTime = 1300;

// Minimum time to spend in a stall
private int minInStallTime = 1500;

// Maximum time to spend in a stall
private int maxInStallTime = 2000;
private long startWaitTime;

public Person(Bathroom bathroom, boolean isMale) {
    this.bathroom = bathroom;
    this.isMale = isMale;
}

/**
 * Determines how long a person has been waiting in the queue.
 *
 * @return The length a person has been waiting.
 */
public long getWaitingTime() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - startWaitTime;
}

/**
 * Returns gender of person.
 *
 * @return true indicates male, false indicates female.
 */
public boolean isMale() {
    return isMale;
}

/**
 * The run method - called when thread starts.
 */
public void run() {
    // Constantly loop
    // Wait random amount of time before queuing to use the bathroom (±Æ¶?)
    try {
        Thread.sleep((int) (minIdleTime + (maxIdleTime - minIdleTime)
                * Math.random()));
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Queue up for the Bathroom.
    try {
        // Remember the time person started to queue.
        startWaitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Queue in the bathroom - it will sleep until woken up.
        bathroom.enqueuePerson(this);

    }
    catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Now 'bathroom' has woken person up, meaning they are in a stall. (Sb¬~Yþ)
    try {

        // Do something for a random amount of time to represent
        // 'using' the bathroom
        Thread.sleep((int) (minInStallTime + (maxInStallTime - minInStallTime)
                * Math.random()));
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Finished using the bathroom, so inform it.
    try {
        bathroom.offerStall(this);
    } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Loop to begin cycle again.
    while (true) {
        // Wait random amount of time before queuing to use the bathroom
        try {
            Thread.sleep((int) (minIdleTime + (maxIdleTime - minIdleTime)
                    * Math.random()));
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Queue up for the Bathroom.
        try {
            // Remember the time person started to queue.
            startWaitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // Queue in the bathroom - it will sleep until woken up.
            bathroom.enqueuePerson(this);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Now 'bathroom' has woken person up, meaning they are in a
        // stall.
        try {
            // Do something for a random amount of time to represent
            // 'using' the bathroom
            Thread.sleep((int) (minInStallTime + (maxInStallTime - minInStallTime)
                    * Math.random()));
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Finished using the bathroom, so inform it.
        try {
            bathroom.offerStall(this);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Loop to begin cycle again.
    }
}
}
```

Bathroom.java

```
package src2;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Bathroom {

private LinkedList bathroomQueue = new LinkedList();
private LinkedList stallOccupants = new LinkedList();

private int noOfStalls = 5;

// Used as measurements
private int totalFemales = 0;
private long femaleQueueTimeTotal = 0;
private int totalMales = 0;
private long maleQueueTimeTotal = 0;
private int MinUseBathroomTime = 1500;
private int MaxUseBathroomTime = 2000;
private int exitMales = 0;
private int exitFemales = 0;
Person in = null; //the person do not know the sex yet.

/*
  * The JFrame to update in order to show measurements. Not really a very OO
  * way of doings things (e.g., forcing unrelated classes to rely on each
  * other), but works fine for demonstration purposes.
  */
private RunBathroom windowThread;

public Bathroom(RunBathroom windowThread) {
    this.windowThread = windowThread;
}

/**
 * Enters a {@link Person} Person into the queue for the bathroom
 *
 * @param person The {@link Person} Person to enter into the queue
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void enqueuePerson(Person person) throws InterruptedException {
    Person nextInStall;
    // Add person to the queue and then check to see if they're next in line.
    // Lock the object to prevent a context switch allowing someone else
    // enter the queue first
    synchronized (this) {
        bathroomQueue.add(person);
        nextInStall = offerStall(null);
    }
    // If not next in line, put person to sleep
    if (person != nextInStall) {
        synchronized (person) {
            person.wait();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Method the check who is next to enter bathroom
 *
 * @param remove Person to remove from a stall (can be null)
 * @return The Person
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
public synchronized Person offerStall(Person remove) throws InterruptedException {

    Person occupiersGender = (Person) stallOccupants.peek(); //the person in the bathroom.
    Person nextPerson = (Person) bathroomQueue.peek(); //the person in the bathroom queue.
    boolean maleInControl = false; // = false (is a male); 

    // If given, remove the person from a stall
    if (remove != null) {
        removePerson(remove, stallOccupants);
    }
    Person in = null; //the person do not know the sex yet.
    // If no-one is queuing, or if the stalls are full, return null.
    if (bathroomQueue.size() == 0 || stallOccupants.size() >= noOfStalls) {
        in = null;
    } else {
        // Otherwise find next the next person to enter bathroom
/*        Person occupiersGender = (Person) stallOccupants.peek(); //the person in the bathroom.
        Person nextPerson = (Person) bathroomQueue.peek(); //the person in the bathroom queue.
        boolean maleInControl; // = false (is a male);     */

        // If someone is in the bathroom, find out which sex
        if (occupiersGender != null) {
            maleInControl = occupiersGender.isMale(); // stallOc
        }
        // If nobody is in bathroom, then give control to whoever is next in queue
        else {
            maleInControl = nextPerson.isMale();
        }
        // If someone exists in the queue
        if (nextPerson != null) {
            // If the next person is male, and males are in control of the bathroom, or the bathroom is empty
            if (nextPerson.isMale()
                    && (maleInControl || stallOccupants.size() == 0)) {
                in = nextPerson;
            }
            // Otherwise, if next person is female, and females are in control, or the bathroom is empty
            else if (!nextPerson.isMale()
                    && (!maleInControl || stallOccupants.size() == 0)) {
                maleInControl = false; //this is a female.
                in = nextPerson;
            }
            // Otherwise, the next person in the queue cannot yet enter.
            else {
                in = null;
            }
        }
    }

    // If a person was chosen to enter bathroom
    if (in != null) {
        Random r=new Random();
        int i = r.nextInt(5);
        // Remove them from the queue, and update measurements/window
        if (in.isMale()) {
            while(in.isMale()){
                for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                    removePerson(in, bathroomQueue);
                    maleQueueTimeTotal += in.getWaitingTime();
                    totalMales++;
                    Thread.sleep((int) (MinUseBathroomTime + (MaxUseBathroomTime - MinUseBathroomTime) 
                            *Math.random()));
                    windowThread.update(in.isMale(),totalMales, exitMales);
                }
                for(int j = 0; j<=i; j++){
                     Thread.sleep((int) (MinUseBathroomTime + (MaxUseBathroomTime - MinUseBathroomTime) 
                            *Math.random()));
                     exitMales++; 
                     windowThread.update(in.isMale(), totalMales, exitMales);
                }
                in = (Person) bathroomQueue.getFirst();

            }
        } else {
            while(!in.isMale()){
                for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                    removePerson(in, bathroomQueue);
                    femaleQueueTimeTotal += in.getWaitingTime();
                    totalFemales++;
                    Thread.sleep((int) (MinUseBathroomTime + (MaxUseBathroomTime - MinUseBathroomTime) 
                            *Math.random()));
                    windowThread.update(in.isMale(), totalFemales, exitFemales);
                }
                for(int j = 0; j<=i; j++){
                     Thread.sleep((int) (MinUseBathroomTime + (MaxUseBathroomTime - MinUseBathroomTime) 
                            *Math.random()));
                     exitFemales++; 
                     windowThread.update(in.isMale(),totalFemales, exitFemales);
                }
                in = (Person) bathroomQueue.getFirst();
            }
        }
        // Add the person to a stall
        stallOccupants.add(in);
        // Notify the person so as to wake them up
        synchronized (in) {
            in.notify();
        }
    }
    // Return the person
    return in;
}
/**
 * Removes a person from a list
 *
 * @param person Person to remove
 * @param list   Queue/list to remove from
 */
private void removePerson(Person person, LinkedList list) {
    // Iterate through the list and remove the person if found
    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        if (i.next() == person) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
}
}
```

RunBathroom.java

```
package src2;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

/**
 * Application demonstrating a fair solution to the "Unisex Bathroom" problem.
 * Creates the GUI and upon clicking "Start", initialises the {@link Bathroom} and populates
 * the queue with females and males.
 * <p/>
 * A random arrival pattern is used.
public class RunBathroom extends JFrame implements Runnable, ActionListener {
private JLabel totalMales, totalFemales, totalUsers, malestate, femalestate,     exitmale, exitfemale, emptymale, emptyfemale;
private JButton startItem = new JButton("Start");
private JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
private Bathroom bathroom;

// Boolean representing the gender currently occupying the bathroom; true indicates male, false indicates female.
private boolean isMale = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new RunBathroom()).start();
}

/**
 * Constructor which sets up all the necessary components of the GUI.
 */
public RunBathroom() {

    super("Unisex Toilet Problem");
    setSize(700, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

    // Add start button
    startItem.setText("Start");
    startItem.addActionListener(this);
    bottomPanel.add(startItem);
    startItem.setEnabled(false);

    // Add quit button
    quit.addActionListener(this);
    bottomPanel.add(quit);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 2));
    JPanel topPanel2 = new JPanel (new GridLayout(3, 2));
    totalMales = new JLabel("0");
    totalMales.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    totalFemales = new JLabel("0");
    totalFemales.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    totalUsers = new JLabel("0");
    totalUsers.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    malestate = new JLabel ("0");
    malestate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    femalestate = new JLabel ("0");
    femalestate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    exitmale = new JLabel ("0");
    exitmale.setHorizontalAlignment (SwingConstants.CENTER);
    exitfemale = new JLabel ("0");
    exitfemale.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    emptymale = new JLabel ("0");
    emptymale.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    emptyfemale = new JLabel ("0");
    emptyfemale.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    // Add labels
    topPanel.add(new JLabel("Total males: "));
    topPanel.add(totalMales);
    topPanel.add(new JLabel("Total females: "));
    topPanel.add(totalFemales);
    topPanel.add(new JLabel ("Male state: "));
    topPanel.add(malestate);
    topPanel.add(new JLabel ("Female state: "));
    topPanel.add(femalestate);
    topPanel.add(new JLabel("Number of exit male: "));
    topPanel.add(exitmale);
    topPanel.add(new JLabel("Number of exit female: "));
    topPanel.add(exitfemale);
    topPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
    topPanel.add(emptymale);
    topPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
    topPanel.add(emptyfemale);
    topPanel.add(new JLabel("Total Number of persons: "));
    topPanel.add(totalUsers);

    mainPanel.add(topPanel);
    mainPanel.add(topPanel2);
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(mainPanel, "Center");
    contentPane.add(bottomPanel, "South");
    startItem.setEnabled(true);
}

/**
 * When the thread starts, display the GUI.
 */
public void run() {
    setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Exits on close of window
 *
 * @param e Windowevent (close)
 */
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
}

/**
 * Listens for mouse-presses on menu items.
 *
 * @param evt The ActionEvent performed
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    Object source = evt.getSource();

    // If Quit is clicked, exit program.
    if (source == quit) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // If Start is clicked, create a bathroom and add male and female
    // persons to it.
    else if (source == startItem) {
        startItem.setEnabled(false);
        bathroom = new Bathroom(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Thread(new Person(bathroom, !isMale)).start();
            new Thread(new Person(bathroom, isMale)).start();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the labels on the GUI
 *
 * @param isMale      Sex referring to the label to update
 * @param averageTime The average time that gender has had to wait
 * @param totalOfSex  The total number of that gender which has used to bathroom
 */
public void update(boolean isMale, int totalOfSex, int exitOfpeople) {
    if (isMale) {
        totalMales.setText(Integer.toString(totalOfSex));
        exitmale.setText(Integer.toString(exitOfpeople));
        malestate.setText("GOING");
        femalestate.setText("WAITING");
        if (totalOfSex == exitOfpeople){
            emptymale.setText("Everyone can go!");
            emptyfemale.setText(" ");
        }else{
            emptymale.setText("Only for Male");
            emptyfemale.setText(" ");
        }
    } else {
        totalFemales.setText(Integer.toString(totalOfSex));
        exitfemale.setText(Integer.toString(exitOfpeople));
        femalestate.setText("GOING");
        malestate.setText("WAITING");
        if (totalOfSex == exitOfpeople){
            emptyfemale.setText("Everyone can go!");
            emptymale.setText(" ");
        }else{
            emptyfemale.setText("Only for Female");
            emptymale.setText(" ");
        }
    }
    totalFemales.getText();
    totalUsers.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt((totalFemales.getText()))
            + Integer.parseInt((totalMales.getText()))));
}
```

}

There are still 17 errors saying that symbols cannot be found.  I've tried my best to understand but still could not.  Cannot anyone help? :(
The errors shown are below:

`Bathroom.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    Person in = null; //the person do not know the sex yet.
    ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    private RunBathroom windowThread;
            ^
  symbol:   class RunBathroom
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    public Bathroom(RunBathroom windowThread) {
                    ^
  symbol:   class RunBathroom
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    public void enqueuePerson(Person person) throws InterruptedException {
                              ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
    public synchronized Person offerStall(Person remove) throws InterruptedException {
                                          ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
    public synchronized Person offerStall(Person remove) throws InterruptedException {
                        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:180: error: cannot find symbol
    private void removePerson(Person person, LinkedList list) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        Person nextInStall;
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
        Person occupiersGender = (Person) stallOccupants.peek(); //the person in the bathroom.
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
        Person occupiersGender = (Person) stallOccupants.peek(); //the person in the bathroom.
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
        Person nextPerson = (Person) bathroomQueue.peek(); //the person in the bathroom queue.
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
        Person nextPerson = (Person) bathroomQueue.peek(); //the person in the bathroom queue.
                             ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
        Person in = null; //the person do not know the sex yet.
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:142: error: cannot find symbol
                        in = (Person) bathroomQueue.getFirst();
                              ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
Bathroom.java:161: error: cannot find symbol
                    in = (Person) bathroomQueue.getFirst();
                          ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Bathroom
15 errors`

Comment: Show us the code for the `Person` class.

Comment: Please add the error messages as **text** to the question, not as a (linked) screenshot. Also, by "running" you probably mean "compiling" - that is quite a difference

Comment: It isn't the code we need to see - it is the command line you use to compile it.  Do you really have classes called Person.java and RunBathroom.java or should you have left the .java part off the import?

Comment: Please show the command which you're compiling with and your packages structure.

Comment: I simply don't believe that the code that you have shown us *ever* compiled.  You must have "tweaked" it, and the "tweaking" has introduced compilation errors.  Interestingly, the compilation errors that you would get don't match the compilation errors that you have shown us.  More evidence of "tweaking".

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated the post! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I used javac Person.java Bathroom.java RunBathroom.java to compile it.  Is it the proper way to do so?

Comment: @AndreasFester I have added it.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import Person.java;
import RunBathroom.java;
```

It's so unususal to see package name with .java suffix. Please check your import statement and package name of Person class.

Comment: This doesn't explain what the code was (supposedly) working before.  But I think that the explanation is that this is not the code that was working before.  These classes ... as shown ... will not compile in Eclipse either.  The imported class names are wrong.  That should give you a compilation error.

Comment: I deleted the above ones now.  I am extremely new to java and may I know how to compile and execute three of the files at the same time? And what does the error saying that the symbols are not found mean? It was not able to read the variables in the other two files? Thanks in advance! :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a software from the ide and not from command line you need to check if there is any difference from your command line and your ide configuration. In particular:

- If you are using the same JVM
- If you are using the same classpath
- If you use any file system resource you need to check if the base directory is the same
- If you are starting your application with some particular run time parameter

Comment: May I know if downloading a more updated linux environment help to solve my problem?  Thanks for answering :)